# Unable to execute statement in php only when user selects yes in dialog box

Tags: php, mysql, confirm

Hi am trying to insert data into mysql only when user enters yes in confirm dialog but the data always inserted into mysql even if the user enters no.Here is my code..

```
<?php if (mysqli_num_rows($data_query) >= 1) { ?>
    <script>
        var txt;
        var r = confirm('Duplicate Data! Click OK to Add & Cancel to Cancel it')
        if (r == true) {
            <?php
                $query="INSERT INTO video_data(date) " ;
                $query .= "VALUES('{$date}')";
                $create_video_query=mysqli_query($connection,$query);

                if (!$create_video_query) {
                    die("failed".mysqli_error());
                } else {
                    $success = "Video added succesfully"; 
                }
            ?>
        }          
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Can you check your console whether it showing any error or not

Comment: @FairyDancer its not showing any error

Comment: Replace your php code with `alert()` whether it show on only true case

Comment: PHP code will only be executed on server side.

Comment: @ravisachaniya yes it will be executed on server side

Comment: @FairyDancer yeah its not to if statement let me chek

Comment: @FairyDancer yeah am able to show alert unable to show text using echo when executing through php

Answer (score 0):

Test your code without the php.

1. you are missing a semicolon after "Click OK to Add & Cancel to Cancel it')"
2. Make sure you really have "if(r==true)" and **not** "if(r=true)"

I tested the following code (php is removed) and it works:

```
     <html>
     <body>
     <script>
        var txt;
        var r = confirm('Duplicate Data! Click OK to Add & Cancel to Cancel it');
        if(r==true){
            alert('Clicked OK: Run insert sql');
        } else {
            alert('Clicked Cancel: Do nothing');
        }          
     </script>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: yeah while using php in if statement I have used like this <?php echo "hello" ; ?> then its showing error as hello not defined

Comment: If you put <?php echo "hello" ; ?> inside the javascript section then it may try to run "hello" as javascript code, hence the undefined variable error as it is looking for a variable called "hello". Instead try:
   alert('<?php echo "hello" ; ?>')

Answer (score 0):

You can not mix server-side (PHP) and client-side (JavaScript) together to interact in real time together. You have to use AJAX or you have to submit a form (either one built in the html or built by javascript). Here is just a basic example:

```
<?php
# Checks to see if the form has been submitted
if(isset($_POST['add'])) {
    $query="INSERT INTO video_data(date) " ;
    $query .= "VALUES('{$date}')";
    $create_video_query=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    if(!$create_video_query) {
        die("failed".mysqli_error());
    }
    else {
        $success = "Video added succesfully"; 
    }
}          
?>

<?php
# I don't know what this is based on (the query) so I don't know if it's required.
# I just left it
if(mysqli_num_rows($data_query) >= 1) { ?>
<script>
var txt;
var r = confirm('Duplicate Data! Click OK to Add & Cancel to Cancel it');
if(r !== false){
    // Assumes there is a form to submit and submits it
    form.submit();
}
</script>
<?php  } ?>
```

Comment: ACtually am checking for duplicate rows if the duplicate data is entered it will show confirm dialog if user presses yes i need to insert data if there is not duplicate data also i need to insert data when I use form.submit data will be not inserted forever because again it will come same condition

Comment: Ok, so then you have to submit the form when the user confirms and then have your page reload and the PHP will then run OR you run an AJAX script when user clicks ok on the confirm button.

Comment: To be honest, what you are trying to accomplish sounds more like it would be suited to an AJAX set-up. Bottom line though, you can't have the javascript trigger the php in the same page because the PHP runs first to build the page, then the javascript runs after page load. That is why your database hit runs every time you reload the page

Comment: is there any way I can do this

Comment: Yes, you do either ajax or submit a form.

Comment: Yep, Rasclatt is quite right. Ajax suits your needs best as it is interactive. It is a little advanced for a beginner but I'm sure you will manage. 
 
The other way, which is usually simpler for a beginner, is to use the old fashioned method for interacting with the user: a form and submit button => then run the database php code. Rasclatt's example is replacing the usual submit button with javascript code: form.submit(). 
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp